# How To Sanitize WYSIWYG Value In PHP?

Tags: php, strip-tags

I have been trying to use the code below to filter out malicious scripts and allow only the tags mentioned in the filter to be used in the WYSIWYG text bar. But when i am inserting the $filter value into the database, nothing is being inserted. In short the $filter is not getting any filtered values to store. I would like to know whether there is any problem in my code?

```
$description = $_POST['name'];

$filter = strip_tags($description,"<p><a><b><ul><li><ol><u><i><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><br><div><hr><table><tbody><td><tr><tfoot><th><thead><img><strong><em>");
```

Comment: Try to use `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>`  in all of your tags

Comment: Its the same, It is not accepting any kind of values. Nothing is being posted into the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `htmlentities`, which will convert the `<>` into their HTML entity counterparts

```
$filter = htmlentities($description);
```

Another option is to use `strip_tags`, which would remove the tag entirely

```
$filter = strip_tags($description);
```

Comment: $filter = strip_tags($description); - Wouldn't this eliminate the tags for other WYSIWYG elements like <p><h1> as well ?

Comment: The [second argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to `strip_tags` allows you to specify tags you want to keep so you can white list the ones you want